# Right to work in Halacha

Tags: halacha, money, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, employment, modern-times

In secular law, there is a debate as to whether or not a policy known as right to work should exist or whether a policy known as closed shops should exist. To simplify, right to work means you have a right not to join a union and pay dues, and closed shops mean you have to join the union at your workplace and pay dues. Does Halacha have anything to say about this?

Comment: I strongly suspect this is one where Halacha would say *hakol keminhag hasocharim*; "the expectation is to follow the common practice of that town's professionals." For what it's worth, the mid-20th Century immigrant poskim, especially R' Yosef Eliyahu Henkin, tended to think highly of unions. But generally speaking, there are going to be areas of business practice where the halacha is simply "follow the normative practice", which will vary state to state.